# How to rewrite code for a (too) big IF statement?

Tags: swift, loops, if-statement, uibutton, uiimage

I have a project with some `UIbuttons` with different `UIimages` displayed in it. Through user interaction, there could be any of the `UIimages` in the `UIButtons`. There are like around 1000 images in the project. I have initialised a variable named 'i'. And a `IBAction` named buttonTapped on all the buttons. Now I want to update variable 'i'  and use the value of 'i' for every different possible `UIImage'. I can do this with an IF statement as shown here:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "image1") {

    i = 1

    print(i)
    // use the value of i

} else if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "image2") {

    i = 2

    print(i)
    // use the value of i

} else if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "image3") {

    i = 3

    print(i)
    // use the value of i

     } else if // and so on
```

But I would like a better solution then an IF statement with around 1000 else if(s). I have tried, but I am not able to rewrite the code in a concise matter. What could I use instead of the IF statement? Some kind of loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude solution (assuming the indices are all sequential) would be

```
for i in 1 ... 1000 { // or whatever the total is
    if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "image\(i)") {
        print(i)
        // use i
    }
}
```

A better solution, especially if the names are not in the format you give, is to have an array of structs (or just an array of images, if the numbers are all sequential)...

```
struct ImageStruct {
    var image: UIImage
    var index: Int
}
var imageStructs:[ImageStruct]... // Some code to fill these
```

...

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let matches = self.imageStructs.filter( { $0.image == sender.currentImage } )
    if let match = matches.first {
        // use match.index
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the crude solution works for me. the better solution; I will implement that solution later.

Comment: ... it will load (up to) 1000 images from your resources every time the user presses the button! Consider at least preloading all of the images into an array...

Comment: yes, thanks for the advice. I will definitely do that.